How can I display a list of all the years for which there are entries?
I have a section with entries. I only need to get the years for which there are entries. How to do it?

There are lots of different ways to do this. Have you tried anything so far?
You could use the group filter to group all the entries by their postDate year:
{% set entriesGroupedByYear = craft.entries.section('handle').all()|group(entry => entry.postDate|date("Y")) %}

<ol>
    {% for year, entries in entriesGroupedByYear %}
        <li>{{ year }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>


https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/filters.html#group
This will give you a two-dimensional array where the keys are the years and the values are arrays of entries belonging to that year.
If you don't need the actual entry data it might be more efficient to go a bit more manual - for example using map and unique to loop over everything and store into a new array:
{% set years = craft.entries.section('handle').all()|map(entry => entry.postDate|date("Y"))|unique %}

<ol>
    {% for year in years %}
        <li>{{ year }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/map.html
If you're not comfortable with map you could do the same thing with a more lengthy combination of a for loop and the merge or push filters to push all the years into a new array before filtering them with unique, or using conditionals to only add the year if it hasn't already been added.
https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/filters.html#unique
https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/filters.html#push

Your question is a bit confusing.
But, I suppose you are looking for something like that:
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('yourSectionHandle').all() %}
{% for entry in entries %}
  {{ entry.postDate|date('Y') }}
{% endfor %}


no, it will just go through all the elements and display the year from each element. I also need to get a list of the years for which there are items.
